# When electrons move from low potential to high potential, does the kinetic energy supplied per electron remain the same for each electron?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage

Suppose, I have two conductors $A$ & $B$. $A$ has a higher potential  than $B$. Now, let us connect the two by a wire.

Electrons will now move from $B$ to $A$. Now, my question is that will the kinetic energy supplied per electron be the same? One may say that it is, and the magnitude of the energy per coulomb of electrons is the voltage.

But from the formula of voltage, $V=\frac{W}{Q}$, we can see that it only measures the **average** kinetic energy, not the actual kinetic energy supplied to each coulomb of electrons.

So, will the kinetic energy supplied per electron be the same for each electron?

Comment: “Now, my question is that will the kinetic energy supplied per electron be the same?“ Same as what? It’s unclear what you’re asking

Comment: @BobD for each electron

Comment: no for each electron kinetic energy supplied would be different.

Comment: ...it isn't the same in the first place :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, my question is that will
> the kinetic energy supplied per electron be the same? One may say that it is, and the magnitude of the energy per coulomb of
> electrons is the voltage.

The two statements are not equivalent.

Regarding the second statement, yes one may say it is the magnitude of the  (kinetic) energy per coulomb of electrons. But that is not the same thing as saying it is the actual kinetic energy supplied to *each of the 6.2415 x 10$^{18}$ electrons* in a coulomb of charge. As indicated in my other answer, the actual kinetic energy of an individual electron will vary around the average of all the electrons, which is the kinetic energy per coulomb.

> But from the formula of voltage, $V=\frac{W}{Q}$, we can see that it
> only measures the **average** kinetic energy, not the actual kinetic
> energy supplied to each coulomb of electrons.

Again, it is the actual kinetic energy per coulomb of electrons. But it is not the actual kinetic energy of each electron in the coulomb of charge.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The electrons have two types of kinetic energy. One type is due to the random thermal motions of the electrons. That motion exists with or without a voltage. The other type is the result of drift current that they acquire from the electric field. The velocities, and therefore the kinetic energies of individual electrons are distributed around the average. So to answer your question, the kinetic energies of individual electrons are not all the same.

Hope this helps